# How to access an image link inside an object and show it using react componenets

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object (called opp) containing
data in this format

```
  {"randomtext"},
  { "randomtext"}, 
  {flag: "imagelink" , rand1: 23}, 
  {"randometext"}
```

i am trying to access the  value inside the flag property and and with the help of react components show it

my intended result should be

```
<img src=" value in flag property"/>
```

so far i have come up with this

```
class App extends React.Component {
   
      render() {
       
        return (
          <div> 
          {opp.map(item => <Card  value={item} src={item.flag}/>)}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
        ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container1"));
```

the below code is held in another file

```
class Card extends React.Component {   
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>{this.props.value}</h1>
           <img src={this.props.src}/>
           </div>
    
    );
  }
}
export default Card;
```

but whenever i run this it returns a react error saying `"objects are not valid as a react child (found: object with keys { flag, rand1}). if you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead"`

*ps: would accept edits to this post for readability*

Comment: Hi! You opp var contains and array or an object? In any case like suggested by the error message, you're trying to display and object/array directly. You should be more accurate by specifiying the property/index then property to want to display.

Comment: hi the opp is an object not an array,    ill try some code edits to see if that fixes the issue , thanks for the advice

Comment: You're welcome @Yusuf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item is the whole object you pass into card component and you are trying to render in the `h1 tag` of the Card component as value. You should be showing some property value of the object in the h1. e.g this `this.props.value[0]` will show the first property value in h1.

```
class Card extends React.Component {   
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>{this.props.value[0]}</h1>
           <img src={this.props.src}/>
           </div>
    
    );
  }
}
export default Card;
```

Comment: this is the solution apparently i was pushing the entire value of the opp object into the h1 tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>{this.props.value}</h1>
```

value is an object and you are trying to render it in header. Hence the error.

If you really want to print the value object you can stringify it.